# PHP - SOAP Request

Tags: php, soap, struct, wsdl

I'm trying to send a request to my wsdl, and when a look the function `__getTypes()/__getFunctions()` I have the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => getValuesResponseType getValues(getValues $parameters)
    [1] => ecoResponse eco(eco $parameters)
)

Array
(
    [0] => struct getValues{
 value1 value1;
 value2 value2;
}
    [1] => string value1
    [2] => string value2
    [3] => struct eco {
 string in;
}
```

I don't know how to code this part, I'm a little bit lost
here.
This is what I have done but does not return anything:

```
<?php

    $wsdl = "http://wsdl.example";
    $local_cert = 'local_cert';
    $cert_pass  = 'xxxxx'; 
    $options = array();
    $options['trace'] = true;
    $options['exceptions'] = true;
    $options['local_cert'] = $local_cert;
    $options['passphrase'] = $cert_pass;
    $options['cache_wsdl'] = WSDL_CACHE_NONE;
    $options['soap_version'] = SOAP_1_1;


    $params = array(
      'value1' => 'xxxx',
      'value2' => 'xxxx'
    );
    $request = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://wsdl.example">
                   <soapenv:Header/>
                   <soapenv:Body>
                      <ws:getValues>
                         <value1>xxxx</value1>
                         <value2>xxx</value2>
                      </ws:getValues>
                   </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>';
    $location = $wsdl;
    $action = "http://wsdl.example";
    $version = "1";

    try {
        $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
        $getFunctions = $soapClient->__getFunctions();
        $getTypes = $soapClient->__getTypes();
        $response = $soapClient->__doRequest($request,$location,$action,$version);

        echo '<pre>';        
        print_r($getFunctions);
        print_r($getTypes); 
        print_r($response);    
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage(), '<br />', $e->getTraceAsString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to easily construct the request and easily handle the response, you should use a WSDL to php generator such as the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project which uses the native PHP SoapClient class.

Comment: Well I'm going to try this! And I was able to solve another one of the errors that I had that was failed to load external entity!
Thank you